# Moving TFS 2012 collection to a new server with the same name

Tags: tfs

My ultimate goal is to detach a collection from Server A and move it to Server B. Both are running TFS 2012. The catch is, there is a collection on Server B with the same name as the collection I want to move from Server A. Is there an easy way to move the collection from Server A into Server B, but have the moved collection be named differently.

For example, if on Server A, I have a collection named Bob and on Server B I also have a collection named Bob, how do I move Bob on Server A to Server B so that I have two collections on Server B? I want the original Server B Bob to remain intact, but the Server A Bob to move over to Server A with a new name like Frank.

I don't have a lot of experience moving TFS collections around so detailed steps would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Fire up TFS Admin Console, Stop the Collection, then go to Edit Settings and rename it (and make sure the DB gets renamed too).  Then restart it.  Do this before you migrate it.

[image]